# WP7 App scroll bar on page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have Page in my WP7 Application , this page has some text and some input controls like lists and text boxes, some times when text is more , controls at the bottom of the page disappears. 
Is there any way to show scroll bar on the page so that user can see the whole page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a `ScrollViewer` control can be used to scroll content that is longer than the visible area available to the control ...

```
<ScrollViewer>
 ... content goes here ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the container element that contains all these elements in a `ScrollViewer`.